# How read json file using php

Tags: php, json

My JSON file is like this and I want to read this file in PHP:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "time": 1383458400,
            "summary": "Mostly cloudy throughout the day.",        
        },
        {
            "time": 1383458400,
            "summary": "Mostly cloudy throughout the day.",        
        }
    ],
    "data": [
        {
            "time": 1383458400,
            "summary": "Mostly cloudy throughout the day.",        
        },
        {
            "time": 1383458400,
            "summary": "Mostly cloudy throughout the day.",        
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I read this file in PHP? I am using the following to read:

```
$str = file_get_contents('files/filenameme.json');
$json = json_decode($str, true);
```

Comment: What is the error/problem you're facing ?

Comment: Your actual question is probably "how to traverse an array". If so, show what you tried, or explain your thoughts/difficulty to come up with an approach.

Comment: i can read only first part of json file not other

like
 "data": [
        {
            "time": 1383458400,
            "summary": "Mostly cloudy throughout the day.",        
        },
        {
            "time": 1383458400,
            "summary": "Mostly cloudy throughout the day.",        
        }
    ]

but other json file i am unable to read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you write the JSON by yourself?

You have two problems there: the "data" is a duplicate, and this should be unique like "data1", "data2". The other problem is the comma after the summary part -- it doesn't belong there.

If you fix these issues you should be good to go.

Comment: Both fixed how to get output using foreach?

Comment: You have an array within an array there. So if you use for each, you'll go in the data part, after that you need to select the other arrays within in the data part. 

foreach ( $json as $item ) {
  foreach ( $item as $value ) {
   echo $value['time'];
   echo $value['summary'];
  }
 }